# Reassigning My Variable

Tags: javascript

I do not understand why my code won't console log out the "sum" and "salesTax" variables correctly when I make the selection "American Sales Tax". The console log prints blank. Did I mess up the if syntax?

```
 <input type="number" id="num1">
 <input type="number" id="num2">
  <select id="tax">
    <option>American Sales Tax</option>
    <option>European Sales Tax</option>
  </select>
  <button id="submit" onclick="calculate()" style="margin-left: 10px">Calculate</button>


  <script>
  function calculate(){
    const a = document.getElementById("num1").value;
    const b = document.getElementById("num2").value;

    let sum = parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b);
    let salesTax = document.getElementById("tax").value;

    if (document.getElementById("tax").value === "American Sales Tax"){          
      return salesTax = sum * .0825;
    }
  console.log(sum);
  console.log(salesTax);
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: Where is the `console.log`?

Comment: oops sorry let me fix

Comment: Just a head's up. `submit` will work as an ID, but strange/bad things will happen if you ever try to NAME a form element `submit`.  You're better off using another value there.  Also, it is better practice to put things like that on the `onsubmit` event, since there are other ways to submit a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `return` statement inside of your `if` conditional. Any code after a `return` statement is ignored, as a `return` statement **[ends function execution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)** when it is encountered. That is why you see output for the European Sales Tax (which does not enter the `if` conditional), but *not* for the American Sales Tax.

To correct this, simply **assign** `salesTax` inside of the conditional rather than `return` it:

```
salesTax = sum * .0825;
```

This can be seen in the following:

```js
function calculate() {
  const a = document.getElementById("num1").value;
  const b = document.getElementById("num2").value;

  let sum = parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b);
  let salesTax = document.getElementById("tax").value;

  if (document.getElementById("tax").value === "American Sales Tax") {
    salesTax = sum * .0825;
  }
  console.log(sum);
  console.log(salesTax);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="num1">
<input type="number" id="num2">
<select id="tax">
    <option>American Sales Tax</option>
    <option>European Sales Tax</option>
  </select>
<button id="submit" onclick="calculate()" style="margin-left: 10px">Calculate</button>
```